# get data from coroutine globalScope in Room database kotlin

Tags: kotlin, android-room, kotlin-coroutines, global-scope

I want to fill the `ProductList` in the code below but it's always null.
do you have any solution?

```
fun nameValidation(name: TextInputEditText, cactusDao: CactusDao): String? {

            val nameText = name.text.toString()
            var productList = listOf<String>()
            GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                productList = cactusDao.getAllProductNames()
            }

            if (productList.contains(nameText)) {
                return "Product already Exists!"
            }


            if (nameText.isNullOrEmpty() || nameText.isNullOrBlank()) {
                return "Field is Empty!"
            }

            return null
        }
```

i expected it fills the `ProductList`, but nothing happened. `ProductList` is still null and the condition doesn't work

UPDATE(doe to request of
[darjow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12244168/darjow)):

i used that `nameValidation` here:

```
productName.setOnFocusChangeListener { _, focused ->
            if (!focused) {
                productNameContainer.helperText =
                    ProductValidator.nameValidation(productName, cactusDao)
            }
        }
```

which is inside of `AlertDialog` class that handles alertDialogs.

and im using this `AlertDialog` class in a `floatingActionButton.setOnClickListener{}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330766/why-does-my-function-that-calls-an-api-or-launches-a-coroutine-return-an-empty-o?r=Saves_AllUserSaves) for an explanation of what your issue is.

The correct way to solve this is to turn this into a suspend function that directly calls the suspend function in the DAO:

```
suspend fun nameValidation(name: TextInputEditText, cactusDao: CactusDao): String? {

    val nameText = name.text.toString()
    val productList = cactusDao.getAllProductNames()

    if (productList.contains(nameText)) {
        return "Product already Exists!"
    }

    if (nameText.isNullOrEmpty() || nameText.isNullOrBlank()) {
        return "Field is Empty!"
    }

    return null
}
```

Then the function that calls this function should also be turned into a suspend function, and so on up the chain until you get to the beginning of your logic flow, which might be inside a lifecycle method like `onCreate()` or inside a click listener, etc. At this location, launch a coroutine that handles all the sequential logic you have inside a single `launch { }` block.

And don't use GlobalScope! Use `lifecycleScope`, or if you're in a Fragment, use `viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycleScope`.

---

Based on your comment, this is how you should call it if this code is in an Activity:

```
productName.setOnFocusChangeListener { _, focused ->
    lifecycleScope.launch {
        if (!focused) {
            productNameContainer.helperText =
                ProductValidator.nameValidation(productName, cactusDao)
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: i tried to make  `nameValidation` function susped. but the problem is here: `productName.setOnFocusChangeListener { _, focused ->
                if (!focused) {
                    productNameContainer.helperText =
                        ProductValidator.nameValidation(productName, cactusDao)                         
}       }`                             if `nameValidtion` becomes suspend, i cant use it inside this `setOnFocusChangeListener`

Comment: Yes you can, by launching a coroutine from inside your focus change listener, as I explained in the second paragraph above. In your case, the “beginning of your logic flow” is the focus change listener. See updated answer.

Comment: Thank you so much, your solution helped. this is kinda my first project. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

as https://stackoverflow.com/a/76972694/12244168 explains make your nameValidation method suspend.

```
productName.setOnFocusChangeListener { _, focused ->
    if (!focused) {
        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
            val validationMessage = nameValidation(nameText, cactusDao) 
        }
    }
}
```

You don't want to call runblocking as it will freeze the UI. Therefore you use Dispatchers.Main to execute the async operation. It will call a new coroutine in the background to execute the async operation.

Comment: it makes my nameValidation function suspend and im using it in a OnFocusChangeListener. how to prevent it?

Comment: The project I'm working on is a simple project and unfortunately it doesn't have a ViewModel. is it possible to fix the problem or i have to us MVVM?

Comment: Please update your question with the place you're calling the function so I have a better insight

Comment: There's no reason to enforce the main dispatcher to run this code.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get null is `cactusDao.getAllProductNames()` ran in another thread asynchronously.

You can address the issue by replacing

```
GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
   productList = cactusDao.getAllProductNames()
}
```

with

```
productList = runBlocing {
   cactusDao.getAllProductNames()
}
```

But the better solution is introduce an CoroutineScope on call site and make nameValidation a suspend method.

Comment: using runBlocking inside a place where UI intractions are is dangerous, because it may cause ANR problem.

Comment: Agree. That's why I metioned better solution in my answer.

Comment: This one helped, but as far as I know, using this with UI interaction is dangerous like what @Sep said. the problem is I can't use that suspend function chain in that `setOnFocusChangeListener()`